# Finding $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x^{3/2}\cdot\sin\frac1x$

Tags: limits

How would I go about solving this problem? Not really sure where to start.

Comment: HINT;  $\sin(1/x) \sim 1/x$ as $x\to \infty$.

Comment: so far I've done something like this: let y = 1/x, sin(y)/y^3/2.

Answer (score 1):

Put $y = \dfrac{1}{x} \implies x = \dfrac{1}{y}\implies L = \displaystyle \lim_{y \to 0} \dfrac{\sin y}{y\sqrt{y}}= \infty$

Answer (score -1):

Let $h=\frac{1}{x}$

As $x\to \infty ,h\to 0$.

So $x^{\frac{3}{2}}{\sin{\frac{1}{x}}}=\dfrac{\sin h}{h^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

Put $h^{\frac{3}{2}}=t\implies h=t^{\frac{2}{3}}$

So $\dfrac{\sin h}{h^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\dfrac{\sin t^{\frac{2}{3}}}{t}=(\dfrac{0}{0})\text{as} t\to 0$

Applying L'Hospital's Rule ,we get $\dfrac{\cos t^{\frac{2}{3}}\times\frac{2}{3}}{t^{\frac{1}{3}}}$

which tends to $-\infty $ as $t\to 0^{-}$ and tends to $\infty $ as $t\to 0^{+}$

So the limit does not exist.

Comment: L'Hospital's rule is only valid when the resulting limit exists.

Comment: @MathMajorwhen I applied L-Hospitals Rule the resulting limit existed it was $\frac{0}{0}$

Comment: The limit is $\infty$, and exists in that sense.

Comment: How is it $\infty $? Please see my answer ;In one case it's $\infty\text {other}- \infty $

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+x+to+infinity+x%5E(3%2F2)*sin(1%2Fx)

Comment: why is it $\frac{0}{\infty}$ it is $\frac{0}{0}$ @DonAntonio as $h\to 0 h^{3/2}\to 0$

Comment: @learnmore Of course, you're right (not good watching two different questions at the same time...). Thanks. Anyway, you seem to have forgotten after that that *in fact* $\;h\to 0^+\;$ , not merely $\;h\to0\;$ . The limit exists and it is infinity...and I shall delete my prior comment to avoid future confusions.

Comment: @DonAntonio;Will you please comment where is the problem exactly in my solution;It's very hard to figure out